# Alarm-like app got rejected by app store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

My app has a feature called "Alarm". It will make the phone vibrate and play sound repeatedly (for 5 times, about 10 seconds) when users near some specific place.

In order to make it works even when the screen is off, I have to enable UIBackgroundMode for location service and audio. However, after reviewing process, my app is rejected because:

> The audio key is intended for use by applications that provide audible content to the user while in the background, such as music player or streaming audio applications.
>
> Please revise your app to provide audible content to the user while the app is in the background or remove the "audio" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key.

I did tell them that this is an 'alarm-like' feature but nothing changed. 
How can I make it vibrates and sounds multiple times without 'Audio background mode' or should I summit an appeal to Apple Review Board ?

> If you feel that this rejection was made in error, and believe your app is in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines, you may submit an appeal to the App Review Board

Thank you.

Comment: so where should I ask this question ? Anyway, you're wrong, I did ask about programming: "How can I make it vibrates and sounds multiple times without 'Audio background mode'"

Comment: Is there a reason that presenting a notification isn't enough? That is what I would do and probably what apple wants you to do. This way your "alarm" will be guaranteed to fit the users sound and vibrate preferences.

Comment: To be honest, we received many user feedbacks demanding this functionality because they are usually taking a naps at that point (that's what people do when they have to spend about 2 hours everyday to move by bus). So we have to make this function like an alarm clock.

Comment: Notification sounds can be 30 seconds long. That should be long enough to wake anyone up taking a nap.

Comment: @soulshined I tried that too, it vibrates only once. The bad thing is this doesn't work on ios 6 and users may set their phone on silent, so they may miss their destination.

Comment: Have you seen the latest statistics put out by Apple? Only 3% of their users are running iOS6. I'm just saying.

Comment: I did tell that to my project manager million of times. Did not work. Sad. That's why I have to support iOS 6 in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the audio background mode? If you ask CoreLocation to monitor for a specific region, doesn't it wake up your app in the background?

I am curious if you have you tried this and why you think you need the 'audio hack' to keep your app running.

Comment: Yes it does update location, but when the screen is off, it doesn't sound at all.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that because your app does not fit the narrow guidelines and thought process at Apple of what a third-party app should do, you will have to get creative with the review process.  An appeal is not a bad idea in this case.

Background modes are extremely restricted because iOS already has a hard time making the battery last a full day with regular use but if you provide them all the information about what your code is doing, they will likely approve it.  You could alternatively add a background audio feature that plays nice sleepy music for the napping commuter so that you have a feature that Apple deems worthy of using the background mode.

Sometimes even just removing the current build and submitting a new one will get you into the queue again - and a different reviewer will approve it.  I  am only speaking from experience here.  The same thing has happened to multiple developers when an update to a previously approved app gets rejected without any actual feature additions and vice-versa.